# Is it possible to convert a DLL to a LIB file to avoid dependency?

Tags: windows, dll, linker

I'm quite confused about linking tips. Supose I have an app that uses a dll, but I do not want to use it, I want to statically link with a lib and avoid the dependency for the dll. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *impossible enough* not to try if you want a solution to your problems instead of a bunch of new problems.

(I've managed to make something like that work a couple of times. One variant used a MemoryModule and loading from memory, another one used a heuristic to find cross-segment relocations and fix them up to re-separate code and data sections. Neither was remotely like something you may recommend to a person confused about linking tips).